# Cucumber With JUnit Undefined Step Exception

Tags: junit, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I'm new to the UnitTesting and Cucumber, and today I tried to implement a simple example from a tutorial in Eclipse and I got error when I try run the RunnerClass.java.

My Pom file

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>belajar1</groupId>
  <artifactId>belajar1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>9</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  
  <dependencies>
 
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0-beta4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
<version>6.10.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
<version>6.10.2</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

My feature file

```html
Feature: Gmail Testing
Scenario: Gmail Login

Given url opened
Then enter user id and click next
Then enter password
And click login

Scenario: Gmail Close

Then Close browser
```

My Definition file

```html
public class stepDefinition {

   public static WebDriver obj=null;

   @Given("^url opened$")
    public void url_opened() throws Throwable{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\Installed APP\\Eclipse Workspace\\Webdriver\\geckodriver.exe");
    obj=new FirefoxDriver();
    obj.manage().window().maximize();
    obj.get("https://mail.google.com");
    }
    
  @Then("enter user id and click next")
   public void enter_user_id_and_click_next() throws InterruptedException{
      obj.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("YOURUSERID");
      obj.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
      Thread.sleep(2000);

   }

  @Then("^enter password$")
   public void enter_password(){
   obj.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("YOURPASSWORD");

   }

@Then("^click login$")
   public void click_login() throws InterruptedException{
      obj.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
      Thread.sleep(6000);

   }

@Then("^close browser$")
   public void close_browser(){
      obj.quit();

   }


}
```

My Runner file

```html
package tester;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
    
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(
features="src/test/resources/demo.feature",
glue="definition.stepDefinition",
plugin = {
        "pretty", 
        "html:target/report", //create a folder called cucumber
        "json:target/report.json", 
        //Notice the corresponding file extension (.json) telling cucumber to create a file
//      "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/report.html"
        //Notice I remove the white space at :target/report.html
    }
)

public class RunnerClass {
}
```

I keep got this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSJ0k.png)

Also this my Library

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e408C.png)

Comment: Glue should be a package, looks like maybe your are referencing your stepDefinition class - glue="definition.stepDefinition"

Comment: Thank you after changing glue to package, this works.